# How to make Dragon Naturally Speaking work with multiple MS Windows users?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I'm attempting to use Dragon Naturally Speaking (15.3) to dictate into Emacs (version 26.3). I have two accounts using Windows 10 on the same laptop. From one account, Dragon inserts text into Emacs with no problems. However, on the other account Dragon only accepts commands.

I have tried:

- using dictation box *and* unselecting "Use dictation box with unsupported applications." under options>misc.
- creating a new user profile from scratch from the account that can't use dragon with emacs

Opening Emacs with `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q` has no effect. It still works from the account it works from and doesn't work from the other.

The problem appears deeper than emacs. Here's a summary:

Account B: no problems

Account A works with: Google chrome including Google docs, notepad, entering commands with Emacs.

Doesn't work with: editing text in Emacs, libreoffice writer, the Windows command line.

Comment: Just to be sure the problem doesn't come from `site-lisp.el`, be sure to try `emacs -Q` (uppercase `Q`) too.

Comment: Can you dictate into other programs (notepad or some such) from the second account?

Comment: I wonder if we should close this question for this forum because it turns out not to be an Emacs specific problem.